# When using subprocess.Popen, the output of mongoexport is in stderr

Tags: python, mongodb, subprocess, mongoexport

I'm trying to export my MongoDB collection into a JSON file, and according to [`subprocess.Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) I can use something like this:

```py
from time import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired

filename = f"products - {int(time())}.json"
try:
    process = Popen(
        [
            "mongoexport",
            "--jsonArray",
            "--pretty",
            f"--db=dbname",
            "--collection=products",
            f"--out={filename}",
        ],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE
    )
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(timeout=10)
    print(str(stdout))
    print()
    print(str(stderr))
except TimeoutExpired:
    error_message = (
        "commands.py - export() - "
        "timeout - killing process"
    )
    logging.error(error_message)
    process.kill()
except Exception as e:
    error_message = (
        "commands.py - export() - "
        f"couldn't export - {e}"
    )
    logging.error(error_message)
```

The program runs successfully and the file is created, but those `stdout` and `stderr` variables are not what I exptected. This is printed to the console:

```sh
b''

b'2021-05-23T12:02:12.119+0430\tconnected to: mongodb://localhost/\n2021-05-23T12:02:12.242+0430\texported 1761 records\n'
```

So `stdout` is empty and the *successful message* is in `stderr`. But the order of tuples is the same as the example given in the link I provided:

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

What's going on?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to further check the output of `stderr` to make sure everything went according to plan.

Comment: As an aside, you should probably replace all of that code with a single `subprocess.run()` invocation. You are just reimplementing code which already exists in the standard library, with the usual risks of bugs and omissions.

Answer (score 2):

stderr is often used for logging, with stdout being used for program output.

Thus, for a program that dumps a database, the dump itself might be printed to standard output and the informational messages printed to standard error.

Comment: This answer was useful to me and thus upvoted, but logging to stderr is just a dumb idea.

Comment: Without this SFO I would have never known this hidden behaviour.  Using the `stderr` to write output when there are no actual errors - never seen such a design before.